# group a double value in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I would like to group id 
so as to have an id count.
here is my code

```
 <?php
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
 $records[] = $row;     
        }

 foreach($records as $row){ 
  echo $row['id'] ."<br>"; 
 }

?>
```

outpout :

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    4
    4
    5
```

i want

```
    1
    2
    3
    4 (3)
    5
```

how can I do?
thank you very much for the help

Comment: Look at `array_count_values`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below snippet,

```
$result = array_column($records,'id');
$temp = array_count_values($result); // get number of occurences
ksort($temp,SORT_NATURAL); // sort by key
foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ($value > 1 ? '(' . $value . ')' : '')."<br/>";
}
```

[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) — Counts all the values of an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_count_values` with `array_column`

```
$r = array_count_values(array_column($records, 'id'));
foreach($r as $k => $v){
 echo $k;
 echo ($v>1) ? " ({$v})" : '';
 echo '<br/>';
}
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/EJSCP

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just use `array_count_values`. The return will be an associative array with the count of appearence of each value in your parent array.

Just do something like that:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];

$count = array_count_values($array);

var_dump($count);
```

And the output will be:

```
array (size=5)
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 1
  3 => int 1
  4 => int 3
  5 => int 1
```